# Split string using star in C++

Tags: c++, string, split

I have to split a string based on star (*). For example if I get a string like `"a*a"` then I have to get result `"a"`, i achived this result in C++ by split string API. But if i get a string like `"12*12*12*12"` then I have to get `"12*12"` as result. I have a idea to achieve this by take middle star position and split the string. Is that possible to achieve by STL regular expression or any other simple way.

Thanks
Ramkumar

Comment: what happens if your input is `12*12*12` ?

Comment: it never happen, because I am getting this string from other module and it always to replicate the string and put star between them ( string1 * string1). I cant change that behavior of that module...

Comment: Do you mean the information repeats n times? How dumb is that exactly?

Answer (score 3):

After the comments, I came to conclusion that `split` is not well suited in this case. Use `substr` instead.

```
 int len = str.length();
 string splittedPart = str.substr(len/2 + 1); //second half
```

Comment: Exactly, the star is irrelevant, you're splitting out half the string.

Answer (score 1):

Why not keep on splitting on Star and put the result in a vector. Then you can easily retrieve the first and the second half of the original string from the vector. And think about what happens if you have an even number of stars

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure you will always have odd number of stars, find that middle old one:

```
std::string input;
std::vector<unsigned> star_positions;

for (unsigned i = 0; i < input.size(); ++i)
{
    if (input[i] == '*')
        star_positions.push_back(i);
}

unsigned split_position = star_positions[star_positions.size()/2];

std::string input_L = input.substr(0, split_position);
std::string input_R = input.substr(split_position+1, input.size());
```